# Is any way to inverse a png image's colors by CSS or jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am making a music player based on SoundCloud API. And would like to use the waveform image. But the waveform that SoundCloud provides is not suitable for my needs. In fact the waves are transparent and around them has white colour. I would like to fill the waves by a background image and remove the white colour from around the waves.

Here is an example of the Waveform by SoundCloud: http://w1.sndcdn.com/ZnIW9DSkAhPU_m.png

The attached image is what I am looking for:  [image]

I could find some clues like using:

```
-webkit-mask-box-image: url(https://w1.sndcdn.com/cWHNerOLlkUq_m.png);
background: #81D8D0;
```

or HTML5 Canvas but I couldnt turn them to what I want. Also There is waveform.js but it only takes colors not image as the color of the waveform.

Any idea?

Comment: basically you'd like to use the soundcloud image as a mask if I am getting it right. right?

Comment: @Matyas yes exactly. Like the attached image. So otter image would go transparent and inner colour would hold a background image

Comment: Just finished an allnighter, and working on a fiddle to relax :) (`canvas` solution)

Comment: @Matyas It would be really good if it works by canvas. But they said canvas has cross domain issue so cant get the waveform from soundcloud api. Maybe it has fixed by now

Comment: But I don't get it, isn't this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/7E5hS/ . The only problem seems to be the grayish outside color

Comment: @Matyas Yes, thats what I want. Only problem is that graying colour. it would be perfect if we could get rid of that.

Comment: Some time past since our last conversation, and I've found the interesting question between my bookmarks. So this time I solved it properly: see answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if an ImageMagick solution is permitted as you asked for CSS, but you could potentially do this in PHP and then send it to your browser...

Step 1: Make your wave.png file contain true (255) whites (so we can remove them on Step 3)

```
convert wave.png -threshold 50% PNG32:w1.png
```

Step 2: Composite your Einstein with the wave

```
composite w1.png einstein.jpg x.png
```

Step 3: Replace all white pixels with transparent ones and save resuilt as `out.png`

```
convert x.png -transparent white out.png
```

ImageMagick is free, powerful and available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Note that the last two steps could be simplified into a single step like this:

```
composite w1.png einstein.jpg png:- | convert png:- -transparent white out.png
```

I didn't bother about matching the geometry too much ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Yes there is

#### Try it below or on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/7E5hS/)

It is possible to solve the problem using an embedded svg element, using which you can perform the necessary image transformations

## Steps

1. Convert the wave image into a black & white image
2. Create a mask using the b&w image from above
3. Apply the mask over the background image
4. Add an additional progress element with the same mask applied

```js
/* Small animation logic to move the progress bar*/
var progress = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  document.querySelector('#progress').setAttribute('width', ((progress++) % 100) + '%');
}, 50);
```

```css
#track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #87e0fd;

  /* Just a background gradient*/
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #aaa 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #efefef), color-stop(100%, #aaa));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #aaa 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #aaa 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #aaa 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #efefef 0%, #aaa 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#aaa', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<svg id="track">
  <defs>
    <filter id="color-change">
      
      <!-- Transforms the wave into a fitting b&w mask-->
      <feColorMatrix values="
                -2 0 0 0 1
                0 -2 0 0 1
                0 0 -2 0 1
                0 0 0 0 1
                " />
    </filter>
    
    <!-- define a mask as the waveform image with the above filter applied -->
    <mask id="mask">
      <image id="wave" xlink:href="http://w1.sndcdn.com/ZnIW9DSkAhPU_m.png" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#color-change)" preserveAspectRatio="none" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!--Display the background image with the mask applied-->
  <image x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ls_ukHfuaGg/U7cdwhR1OMI/AAAAAAAALQ4/ZxHrgkz9fH8/s506/Capture+du+2014-07-04+23%3A31%3A40.png" preserveAspectRatio="none" mask="url(#mask)" />
  
  <!-- Display a progress rectangle with the mask applied, and alpha .5 -->
  <rect id="progress" x="0" y="0" height="100%" fill="rgba(255,0,0,.5)" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
img {
 -webkit-filter: invert(100%);  
}
```